# OUI for oracle db 19c not getting started.Tried to install java latest version

Tags: oracle

I just downloaded oracle 19 c from oracle official site and tried to install oracle database for practice and learning.

When I click on statup (Run as Administrator) ,OUI is not getting Started up.

Can any one suggest me??

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I resolve this issue.

Its simple.

My Path where oracle setup was stores contains space in archive folder name.I deleted the space in name between path and OUI started successfully.